# SELECT lines even if a JOIN fails

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select

I have the following beginner problem, I guess:

```
SELECT
    dl_dml_projects.*,
    dl_dml_catalogue.*,
    dl_dml_groups.*

FROM
    dl_dml_projects
        JOIN dl_dml_catalogue ON dl_dml_projects.dml_prj_catalogue_id = dl_dml_catalogue.dl_dml_catalogue_id
        JOIN dl_dml_groups ON dl_dml_catalogue.dml_catl_group = dl_dml_groups.dl_dml_groups_id
```

The problem is when A line has no dl_dml_projects.dml_prj_catalogue_id then it seems that this line is not selected and returned.

Is it possible to force these lines with broken links to be also returned. The missing values of the failed join could be NULL for example.

dl_dml_projects.dml_prj_catalogue_id should be an optional link.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to want an outer join or two.  I am guessing a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT p.*, c.*, g.*
FROM dl_dml_projects p LEFT JOIN
     dl_dml_catalogue c
     ON p.dml_prj_catalogue_id = c.dl_dml_catalogue_id LEFT JOIN
     dl_dml_groups g
     ON c.dml_catl_group = g.dl_dml_groups_id;
```

This will keep all rows in the first table.  If there are no matches in the other tables, then the corresponding columns will be `NULL`.

Note that this also introduces table aliases.  These generally make the query easier to write and to read.